# How to run a SQL SP that will pass parameters to a Crystal report template and print to file / save to desktop?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SP that will allow users to print to pdf or save to desktop, using a crystal report template.

The source of where users will be selecting the records to print largely uses SQL for functionality, so ideally need to run this in SQL, though if SQL needs to call another service or file, so long as that won't need admin privileges, it should be ok.

Is this possible in SQL, or would I have to get something like this built in another language like C#?

I tried calling xp_cmdshell but this will need elevated permissions, which is not possible for the server I am on (security risk).

Comment: If this is MS SQL, you could use SQL Agent to run various scripts, stored procedures, etc.  MS SQL itself is a RDBMS and has no mechanism for sending print jobs.

Comment: SQL Agent would be to automate the running on the script, but is SQL able to pass parameters to an external application?

Comment: An external application can retrieve data from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Devlin's answer above is the correct approach.
An external application can monitor a **Report_Request** table with columns such as the report (rpt file path and name) to run, parameter value(s), Output Type (Print/Export), Export File, Email_Destination(s)...).

When a new report request record is detected by the external application. it would be processed, and the external application can update the status of that record.

There are existing 3rd-party applications that can handle that use case.
Some of these 3rd-party applications allow you to set the desired processing options for the report (e.g. Output Type, Email options, login info). That can significantly simplify the **Report_Request** table.